# Encode/Decode RTF data with PHP?

Tags: php, rtf, decode, encode

I'm writing a script that will convert one file type to another (for some song presentation software normally used by churches.)  I can not extract all the song lyrics and relevant data from the one file type, now I need to convert it to the other.

The other filetype is stored as RTFdata inside XML nodes.  For example:

```
RTFData="e1xydGYxXGFuc2lcYW5zaWNwZzEyNTJcY29jb2FydGY5NDlcY29jb2FzdWJydGY1NDAKe1xmb250dGJsXGYwXGZzd2lzc1xmY2hhcnNldDAgSGVsdmV0aWNhO30Ke1xjb2xvcnRibDtccmVkMjU1XGdyZWVuMjU1XGJsdWUyNTU7fQpccGFyZFx0eDU2MFx0eDExMjBcdHgxNjgwXHR4MjI0MFx0eDI4MDBcdHgzMzYwXHR4MzkyMFx0eDQ0ODBcdHg1MDQwXHR4NTYwMFx0eDYxNjBcdHg2NzIwXHFjXHBhcmRpcm5hdHVyYWwKClxmMFxmczEyMCBcY2YxIFdpdGggZXZlcnkgYnJlYXRoXApXaXRoIGV2ZXJ5IHN0ZXB9"
```

So first, I need to be able to decode these strings so I can see how they are assembled, but once I figure that out I also need a way to convert strings into this format.

I've searched around on google but found no good solution for encoding or decoding RTFdata with PHP.  Any ideas?

Comment: What you are showing is not RTF data. This is what RTF looks like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format it seems to be obfuscated in some way, I can't recognize  which one. Can you find out what this data is?

Comment: It looks like it is base64 encoded. I ran it through http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp and it showed some RTF codes

Comment: Good call, thank you! I think I initially thought it was Bas64 and tried a converter that apparently didn't work, so I assumed this was just what RTF looked like.  You're right, it is Base64 encoded RTF data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some quick Googling turned this up: [RTFGen](http://www.smartsystems.ro/rtfgen)

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it appears to be exactly what I was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The data you have is base64 encoded.

To get the RTF version, you can run it through base64_decode like this:

```
$rtf = base64_decode($RTFData);
```

Once you have that, you can interpret the RTF data itself and do what you want with it.

If you just want to convert it to plain text for example, you can find a PHP script to do this and how it works here: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php